# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

When I run

```
user-pc> mysql
```

It said

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Amir'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can login with following command:

```
user-pc> mysql -u root -p
```

So I try to find solution for this problem and after a while searching the net it suggested to reset password for user 'Amir', but unfortunately there is no user called 'Amir' in `mysql.user` table as you see in below picture:

[image]

I want to change default user to 'root' and when I run `mysql` command it goes directly into shell. how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to [create the user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) 'amir'@'localhost' and give it the correct permissions.

```
create user 'amir'@'localhost' identified by 'securepassword';
```

Comment: You mean default user was 'Amir' ?

Comment: I guess it was trying to login with "current" user

Comment: is it possible to change 'current' user with root?

Comment: you current user is what ever you are logged into your computer with. I assume you are logged into your system as amir.